# return to same tab after redirection to native app in mobile and back to browser

Tags: redirect, adyen, swish

How to return to same tab in browser when user is redirected to a native app and then back to the browser with a url containing additional query parameters, as it is considered a new page and the browser opens it in e new tab resulting in loss of session.

Answer (score 0):

The native mobile application opens the browser which will by default go into a new tab, this is a standard behaviour although for different platforms (Android and IOS) there might a workaround (better post a new question in the relevant groups/tags).

In case of Adyen when the native application redirects the user to your URL (`returnUrl` specified in the configuration) you can access the `sessionId` (passed as parameter) and reload the Drop-in (or component) reusing the existing session.